# Ionic using number keyboard when input type is text

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building an app in Ionic for which I need to have a mask input where the user can input numbers, but the mask format is 99-99999999-9 (user can input numbers only).  I'm using angular2-text-mask for masking the inputs.

If I have my input as type = number, the app crash when the mask is trying to add a "-" in the input. If I put type = text it works fine! But the keyboard is the regular one, so it's not the best user experience.
I thought that a good solution could be to have input type = text but find the way to show the number keyboard. Is that possible?

EDIT (adding code):

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-    angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { AccountInformation } from '../accountInformation/accountInformation';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-addAccount',
  templateUrl: 'addAccount.html'
})
export class AddAccount {
  account: any;
  item: any;
  public cuitMask = [/[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, '-', /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, /[1-9]/, '-' , /[1-9]/]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,     public alertCtrl: AlertController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.account = this.formBuilder.group({
      number: ['', Validators.required],
      cuit: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

View:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-card>
      <form [formGroup]="account" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Numero de Cuenta</ion-label>
            <ion-input class="input-default" autofocus text-center type="number" formControlName="number"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>CUIT</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="input-default" [textMask]="{mask : cuitMask}" autofocus text-center type="text" formControlName="cuit"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <button type="submit" class="footer-button" [disabled]="!account.valid" ion-button block>AGREGAR</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Please show us your code as this is the fastest way we can see what the issue is.

Comment: Done! but there is no issue with the code, is just that I need to know how to override the input type in order to show the number keyboard but keeping the text type